# powerbi create a new table based on existing table

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

Hi I'm trying to create a new table based on an existing table in power bi, how can I do this?

existing table

[image: existing table]

New table

[image: New table]

New table group column can be exported from table3

Comment: Please use text examples, not picture. This just looks like a group by / summary. In fact if you the correct calculated columns you can just show this in a table visualisation without an intermediate table.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I tried to use text but it gave me a line view in here unfortunately , so i had to use the picture

Comment: Put four spaces in front your text.

Comment: There's also https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ for conversion; choosing "Github Markdown" as the output works for SO too.

Answer (score 0):

Power Query solution

```
let
  Source = Table.FromRows(
    Json.Document(
      Binary.Decompress(
        Binary.FromText(
          "i45WSlTSUUpMBhLJeToK+aW2KYlKsTrRSklAkZRMhHByKVg4GYvqWAA=", 
          BinaryEncoding.Base64
        ), 
        Compression.Deflate
      )
    ), 
    let
      _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true])
    in
      type table [user = _t, status = _t, dn = _t]
  ), 
  #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(
    Source, 
    {{"user", type text}, {"status", type text}, {"dn", type text}}
  ), 
  #"Replaced Value" = Table.ReplaceValue(
    #"Changed Type", 
    "cn, ou=", 
    "", 
    Replacer.ReplaceText, 
    {"dn"}
  ), 
  #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Replaced Value", {"user"}), 
  #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Removed Columns", {"dn"}), 
  #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Removed Other Columns"), 
  #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(#"Removed Duplicates", "Index", 1, 1, Int64.Type), 
  #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(
    #"Removed Columns", 
    {"dn"}, 
    #"Added Index", 
    {"dn"}, 
    "Added Index", 
    JoinKind.LeftOuter
  ), 
  #"Expanded Added Index" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(
    #"Merged Queries", 
    "Added Index", 
    {"Index"}, 
    {"Index"}
  ), 
  #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(
    #"Expanded Added Index", 
    List.Distinct(#"Expanded Added Index"[status]), 
    "status", 
    "Index", 
    List.Count
  ), 
  #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Pivoted Column", "Total", each [ac] + [di])
in
  #"Added Custom"
```